# Characterization of Dirac Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $x_0$ be a point in a set $X$ and $\delta_{x_0}$ the Dirac measure concentrated at $x_0$. Characterize the nonnegative real-valued functions on $X$ that are integrable over $X$ with respect to $\delta_{x_0}$ and the value of $\int_X f \delta_{x_0}$.

Comment: So, begin by telling us your thoughts.  What definitions will be used?

Comment: Dirac measure:

$\delta_{x_0} (E)$ = 0 if $x_0$ $\notin$ $E$ and 1 if $x_0$ $\in$ $E$.

In our case, let $E \subset X$.

Comment: I have no idea where to begin. Can you explain how to do this?

Comment: @JackCasey what is the defintion of measurable function?

Comment: After you answer Norbert's question, then look to see the definition for "integrable" and apply it for these functions, and for this measure.

Comment: Norbert, for $(X, M)$, $E \subset X$ is measurable if $E$ belongs to $M$.

GEdgar, I'm having trouble finding the definition, could you tell me what it is?